# Unable to get the attribute values present in url from httpServletRequest in gwt

Tags: gwt

I'm new to GWT. I got a requirement to get the attribute value from the url. say i've a URL localhost:8080/test/?token=123. here i need 123 to be passed to the server side code.

i tried the following steps.

```
public class testImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet{
    ...    
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest= this.getThreadLocalRequest()
    String token = (String) httpServletRequest.getAttribute("token");
    ...
}
```

here, i get token value as null. can someone tell me if i miss something? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
String token = request.getParameter("token");
```

Comment: hi andrei, 
Thanks, i tried using httpServletRequest.getParameter("token") too. still i'm not able to get the value.
But when i tried printing the value in client page using Window.location.getParameter("token"), i could see the value. Kindly   help. Thanks

Comment: You are using an RPC servlet. You should not pass parameters with it. Read more about RPC: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

Comment: Thanks Andrei. so does it mean i can't get the params in RPC. Currently i get the parameter value in client side(Window.Location.getParameter("token") and passing it to Remote servlet. But i read somewhere it is not recommended. is there any alternative? Thanks in advance.